# While loop breaking after first nested question

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

I'm trying to get my program to work. It's a number guessing game where a user inputs their name, and then the program generates a number 1-100. From there they have to guess the number and the program tells them if their number is higher or lower.

If the user succeeded in guessing the number they have the option to play again. I've programmed this but it breaks after the first number input. Any idea where I went wrong?

```
import random
#importing the randoms
#getting the name from the user
message=("What is your name?")
name=input(message)
#challange message from user 
print("Hello! ", name,"I have a number from 1 to 100! It is your job to try and guess it!")
gamestat=False
while gamestat==False:

#generate number 
    number = random.randint(1,101)
#start the game 
    guess = int(input("start to guess: "))

#GAME LOGIC 
    num_guesses = 1

    while guess != number:       
           if guess > number:
         
                 print("lower")
                 guess = int(input("try again: "))
                 num_guesses +=1
    
       

                 if guess < number:

                       print ("higher")

                       guess = int(input("start to guess: "))

                       num_guesses +=1
           

print("congrats it took you", num_guesses, "tries")

message=("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)")
result=input(message)
if result == "no":
    gamestat= True
```

Comment: I think it may be due to indentation issues. It worked for me once I made sure indentations were uniformly applied within each block. Indentation is very important in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Program indentation is not correct. Try using

```
import random
#importing the randoms
#getting the name from the user
message=("What is your name?")
name=input(message)
#challange message from user 
print("Hello! ", name,"I have a number from 1 to 100! It is your job to try and guess it!")
gamestat=False
while gamestat==False:

#generate number 
    number = random.randint(1,101)
#start the game 
    guess = int(input("start to guess: "))

#GAME LOGIC 
    num_guesses = 1

    while guess != number:       
        if guess > number:
            print("lower")
            guess = int(input("try again: "))
            num_guesses +=1
    
       

        if guess < number:
            print ("higher")
            guess = int(input("start to guess: "))
            num_guesses +=1
           

    print("congrats it took you", num_guesses, "tries")

    message=("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)")
    result=input(message)
    if result == "no":
        gamestat= True
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

As a comment already mentioned, it's an indentation issue.

```
if guess < number:
    print ("higher")
    guess = int(input("start to guess: "))
    num_guesses +=1
```

This block is intended one tab to far, it resides under `if guess > number` and can thus never be reached.
Change your `while loop` to

```
while not gamestat:
    # you can just invert it, same result as comparing to False
    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    # add some try except logic here and in the other inputs if the user doesn't input an int
    guess = int(input("start to guess: "))
    num_guesses = 1
    while guess != number:
        if guess > number:
            print("lower")
            guess = int(input("try again: "))
            num_guesses += 1
        if guess < number:
            print("higher")
            guess = int(input("start to guess: "))
            num_guesses += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code after minor modifications.

One was indentation issue as pointed righty. Apart from this in guess< number block the message was start to guess which is not consistent with above which may cause ambiguity. Also you can remove the common part outside the if block.

```
import random

# importing the randoms
# getting the name from the user
message = ("What is your name?")
name = input(message)
# challange message from user
print("Hello! ", name, "I have a number from 1 to 100! It is your job to try and guess it!")
gamestat = False
while not gamestat:
    # generate number
    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    # start the game
    guess = int(input("start to guess: "))

    # GAME LOGIC
    num_guesses = 1

    while guess != number:
        if guess > number:
            print("lower")

        if guess < number:
            print("higher")
        guess = int(input("try again: "))
        num_guesses += 1
    if number == guess:
        print("congrats it took you", num_guesses, "tries")
        message = ("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)")
        result = input(message)
        if result == "no":
            gamestat = True
```